# Preg_match for a string key

Tags: php, preg-match

does someone know how to make a preg_match and accept only key like this one:

```
YTMG3-N6DKC-DKB77-7M9GH-8HVX7
```

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php --- http://www.google.com --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-match

Comment: This question did not deserve an upvote, IMHO. It showed no effort on their part. It's a "gimme dah codez" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex would be this:

> /^[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}$/

Regex explanation:

**Start regex expression**

> /^

**Capital A-Z and Numerical 0-9**

> [A-Z0-9]

**5 long exactly**

> {5}
>
> ### Dash between sets

End expression

> $/

```
<?php

        $reg = '/^[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}$/';

        $string = 'YTMG3-N6DKC-DKB77-7M9GH-8HVX7';

        preg_match($reg, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        print_r($matches);
     ?>
```

Comment: I rather not throw them a fish, but teach them *how* to fish, IMHO.

Comment: Sometimes you gotta give them the answer so they can learn and see why though, just my opinion.Can't all be a shot in the dark

Comment: The question showed no effort on their part and their track record isn't so hot. First thing I always check.

Comment: Dear Fred, don't judge anyone if you don't know anything about him. We are all here to learn and help each others. I already did effort for 1h, also, it's not necessary to put all my codes here for little fix. Thanks @clearshot66 for your help. Will test and let you know.

Comment: @clearshot66 it's correct to use this one to match both upper and lower case letters in the pattern. $reg = '#[^[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}]#i' '', $_POST['key'];

Comment: A-Z is upper, a-zA-Z is both

Comment: Ok, thanks! I want to make it as useful for other people and give you reputation but it give me message: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.